# Maximal ideals in rings with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Suppose $R$ is a ring with unity, and $I$ is an ideal of this ring.

We define $aR \oplus I=\{ar+i \mid r \in R, i \in I\}$

We know that $\forall a \not \in I :\ aR \oplus I=R$ implies $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Proof: Suppose $I \subset J$ where $J$ is an ideal, and $j \in J$ then $$R=jR \oplus I \subset J$$
so $J=R$.

Also, the following is wrong:
$\exists a \not \in I :\ aR \oplus I=R$ implies $I$ is a maximal ideal.

This is wrong because we can choose $a$ to be a unit. In this case, $aR=R$, and so $aR \oplus I=R$ regardless of whether $I$ is maximal or not.

Now, what if I consider non-unit $a$? That is, Do you think the following is correct:

$\exists$ non-unit $a \not \in I :\ aR \oplus I=R$ implies $I$ is a maximal ideal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = 4\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=7$ we have  $4\mathbb{Z} \oplus 7\mathbb{Z} = R$ since, $4$ and $7$ are coprime.

Moreover $4\mathbb{Z}$ is  not maximal ideal.